# To create multiple profiles in an android app with different settings

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an android app. I don't have much knowledge about it. When my app is opened there should be a "Create Profile" button. When this button is clicked, the necessary data for creating a profile is to be entered like,

Profile name?
Setting 1?
Setting 2?
Setting 3?

Then "Save" button is clicked to create it. Many profiles can be created - Profile 1, Profile 2, Profile 3... These appear in "Profiles" section as a list under "Create Profile" button. These could be arranged alphabetically, by date or by dragging and rearranging in the order preferred by the user.

I know how to create a "Create Profile" button, but don't know how to create Profiles with that. I don't know how to rearrange the created profiles too. I'm using Android Studio. Please tell me all the commands and other things that I should learn in order to create Profiles this way. You can also give me code samples too.

Answer (score 0):

You can store each profile into a local SQLite database. Typically, working with such database on Android is done through [Room library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room), although it is possible to write your own SQL queries with the `SQLiteOpenHelper`. For more information, please consult the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite).